# Бесшовный фон для RelativeLayout

Tags: android

Есть бесшовный фон размером 100х100. Можно ли как на HTML сделать так, чтобы в зависимости от размеров экрана фон повторялся по вертикали и горизонтали в RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 3):

**(drawable) repeat_pic.xml:**

```
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/100x100"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:dither="true" />
```

**layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/repeat_pic"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**Программно:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.100x100);
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
    bitmapDrawable.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую сейчас